# Static Libraray - Copy Files Destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static library inside my project (I can edit the static library).

I am using `Copy Files` in the static library and I want to know where can I see the files I copy.

This is my (original :) Copy Files destination.

[image]

The files should be located in the main project or in the static library folder?

Any help?

More then this, I would like to clean the copied files, How should I do this? 
I am familiar  with `cmd+shift+k` and `cmd+alt+shift+k`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your question is answered. Please mark the answer correct to close this question/thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this tutorial on [Creating a Static Library in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial).

- Build and run your static library.
- Go to Products > Right click on it > Show in finder.

  It will be accessible from your `Products` folder of your static library. `$include/$(PRODUCT_NAME)` as you can see below. Your app will be linked to this library.

Here's a quick demo focussing on static library. It is not subgrouped in an app as you described, but you should get the idea -

[image]